# Firebase push notification not recieving in Android TV box , but recieving fine in in Tab and phone

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-tv

I have implemented FCM push notification and working fine in my Android Phone and tablet but not receiving notification in  Android TV Box. Have any one tried push notification receiving in android TV Box

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: same problem ..have you solve it?

Answer (score -1):

FCM works fine on Android TV, what you're probably experiencing is the lack of a system bar on which to display the notification, but the FCM itself does arrive.

Comment: It's an android TV BOX not android TV

Comment: if the OS is Android TV it makes no difference it being a box or an integrated TV